Excessive Logging After Flutter SDK Update: exportSyncFdForQSRILocked and sendCancelIfRunning Messages
I recently updated my Flutter SDK to the latest version (3.27.0) and am encountering excessive logging in the console whenever I run my Flutter project on an Android device. The logs include repeated messages like these:
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher( 5712): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=false callback=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity$1@775be57
I/MESA    ( 5712): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007aaf063850 hos timage handle 0x70002000000d3
I/MESA    ( 5712): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 168
I/MESA    ( 5712): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007aaf07dd50 hos timage handle 0x70002000000d4
I/MESA    ( 5712): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 170

[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /login
[GETX] Instance "LoginController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "LoginController" has been initialized
I/MESA    ( 5712): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: call for image 0xb400007aaf0633d0 hos timage handle 0x70002000000d1
I/MESA    ( 5712): exportSyncFdForQSRILocked: got fd: 166

These logs seem to originate from Flutter or the Android system and are not helpful for debugging my application. It clutters the console and makes it hard to focus on relevant logs.
What I've Tried

Rebuilding the project (flutter clean and flutter pub get).
Checking for issues in my project code (nothing obvious so far).
Ensuring that all plugins and dependencies are updated to the latest versions.


There is ticket for this here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/160442
But in the meanwhile a temporary solution would be to add --no-enable-impeller to your run command.
Ex: flutter run --no-enable-impeller
Hope that helps.

Temporary Solution (Only for Android Studio Users)

Open Run/Debug Configurations
Navigate to Run → Edit Configurations in Android Studio.



Add the Flag
In the Additional run args section, paste the following:
--no-enable-impeller

Click Apply and then OK to save the changes.





In VS Code, you can use the filter and directly specify that you want to send messages only from Flutter to the Debug Console:


I personally use !/ for filtering the debug output from the android emulator. Like @sergey-ruppel showed.
